# Loading jQuery from local assets in Android for a remote html page

Tags: android, jquery, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to read a local javascript file (jQuery) stored in assets from an Android webview. I do not want to load-with-base-url since my images and html are served remotely.

To Summarize : 
- Load local jQuery (in assets folder) into a remotely loaded page in Android webview.

After long hours of browsing going in vain, I decided to put up this question here. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Define a Javascript Interface like the one below that will read your jquery file from assets directory

   ```
   class JavaScriptInterface {

       @JavascriptInterface
       public String getFileContents(){
           return readAssetsContent("jquery.js");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Update WebView to enable JavaScript and to add JavaScriptInterface defined previously...

   ```
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
   webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android");
   ```
3. Add javascript code snippet in your remote HTML to read the jquery file content through android  JavaScript Interface...

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.innerHTML = window.android.getFileContents();
   document.head.appendChild(s);

   //check if jquery is loaded now...
   if(typeof $ != "undefined") {
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('body').css('background','green');
       });
   } else {
       document.body.innerText = "jQuery NOT loaded";
   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Where is this function readAssetsContent() ?? Do I have to create this or is this a library one ?

Answer (score 3):

**First**, in your Activity, create the static variable `appContext`, which holds the Application Context and function below:

```
 //Initialize Application Context
 private static Context appContext;

 //Get Application Context (for use in external functions)
    public static Context getContext() {
        return appContext;
    }
```

...and set the variable in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`:

```
     //Set application context (for use in external functions)
     appContext = this;
```

**Second**, create class in separate file below:

*File: JavaScriptInterface.java*

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;    

class JavaScriptInterface {        

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getFileContents(String assetName){
        return readAssetsContent(MainActivity.getContext(), assetName);
    }

    //Read resources from "assets" folder in string
    public String readAssetsContent(Context context, String name) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(name);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String str;
            boolean isFirst = true;
            while ( (str = in.readLine()) != null ) {
                if (isFirst)
                    isFirst = false;
                else
                    buf.append('\n');
                buf.append(str);
            }
            return buf.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error", "Error opening asset " + name);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("error", "Error closing asset " + name);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

**Third**, do not forget to initialize your Webview to use JavaScriptInterface:

```
     //Set JS interface from JS/HTML code execution
     mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android");
```

**Fourth**, call the android method `getFileContents()` to load the local resources in your HTML with JavaScript:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
          var s = document.createElement('script');
          s.innerHTML = window.android.getFileContents('js/jquery.min.js');
          document.head.appendChild(s);

          //check if jquery is loaded now...
          if(typeof $ != "undefined") {
              $(document).ready(function() {
                    alert("jQuery is loaded!");
             });
          } else {
                alert("jQuery is NOT loaded!");
          }
       </script>
```

**Note:** the local resource in this example is in `/assets/js/` sub-folder.

Comment: The most important check is that the jsInterface is in a separate file. Explanation is GODLIKE! It's just about what the question is about.

Answer (score -1):

In my html page i just added a tag like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/englArrIni.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/point.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/dataManager.js"></script>
```

When you load you url that will automatically load all the js files. I think this is help you.

Comment: Please leave a comment when you down vote an answer.

Comment: question says remote page. means there is no access to page source, otherwise it was piece of cake

Comment: I missed this answer because of the downvotes and it's a very legitimate answer in some cases (at least in mine). Took me one extra hour to find the (same) solution elsewhere.