# Optimize loading speed of WebView

Tags: android, ios, webview, uiwebview, android-webview

I am using an UIWebView (Android: WebView / WebChromeClient) to show our mobile Web App. The Website, made with jQM, loads very slow.

I already tried to activate the Caching Policy at NSURLRequest (Android: setCacheMode) and saved some assets locally.

Activating the caching is too aggressive and will save all dynamic content either. Saving the assets (JS) and injecting after the Web view has load will destroy the website.

Do you have any further ideas how I can speed up the Web View / Website / native part.

Comment: It would better if you can store js and css as local...and other files from remote ....set everything back  before loading

Comment: Do you have an example for this or a hint? With a local HTML that's include the JS (in Android like file_assets) ??

Comment: I think this may help you.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632646/loading-jquery-from-local-assets-in-android-for-a-remote-html-page ....or for more optimization use webservice(will out only html) and add javascript and css from local using html parser like jsoup