# How to load jquery file in webview from local asstes folder: Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

Using only webview.loadData() with String content **not use any html file** and want to use jquery with it.

content string with some of HTML tags without head and body tag.

Please suggest me how to load jquery without using html file.

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
webView.loadData(content,"text/html; charset=utf-8","UTF-8");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading jQuery from local assets in Android for a remote html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632646/loading-jquery-from-local-assets-in-android-for-a-remote-html-page)